# libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: shell, binary, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install and use a binary package of a DB software but after setting my environment variables in `~/.profile` as following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/DB/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/DB/bin:$PATH
export Data=/path/to/make/db_cluster
```

I am getting the following error:

```
libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I used the following instructions:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev

cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

but still getting errors regarding it when using for example initdb:

```
initdb:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:libssl.so.10 : versio 'libssl.so.10' not found: (required by home/user/dbfolder/lib/libpq.so.5)
```

Any help will be appreciate it.

Answer (score 44):

On CentOS 8 the missing lib is included in the **compat-openssl10** package, just run:

```
yum install compat-openssl10
```

And all works fine...

Answer (score 4):

im in centos,not ubuntu. find libssl.so.10 file first, then cp or ln -s

```
# whereis  libssl.so.10
libssl.so: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 /usr/lib64/libssl.so
```

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10
```

you can look this:
[libssl-so-10-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339364/libssl-so-10-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

[libssl.so.10 & libcrypto.so.10 not found](https://github.com/91yun/serverspeeder/issues/19)

Check the official documentation, use a new system.

Comment: libssl.so.10 exists in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu but for some reason it cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure for centos Linux System for the below error:

> libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

-Run the command `yum provides */libssl*`

It will show compatible version library corresponding to your missing library like for libssl.so.10

- Install the corresponding package libssl.so.xx by using

> `yum install libssl.so.xx`

In the same way if you get **libcrypto.so.10** problem, repeat above steps and replace

> libssl with libcrypto

and follow the steps

This will sort out the missing packages problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on Fedora that needs to do this, I don't recommend installing this because it's not supported anymore. But there are instances where you need this library. How I did it was:

1. Download the `rpm` file from here: https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=compat-openssl10
2. Run `sudo yum install ./RPM_FILE_NAME`